Implementing a context-switching mechanism in asyncio
I wish to create something similar to a context switching mechanism, that allows using a shared resource one at a time.
In my case it's a single session object connecting to a website, and each context would be the current account connected to the website. As a system constraint - no two accounts can be connected at the same time, and the connection is a costly operation.
I have devised the following mechanism which involves letting go of the context (switching account) during expensive background operations:
counter = 0  # i.e. ContextVar for current account
def increase_counter():
  global counter
  counter += 1

def decrease_counter():
  global counter
  counter -= 1

async def run_operation():
  while True:
    operation = operation_queue.get()
    increase_counter()

    task = asyncio.create_task(operation())
    task.add_done_callback(lambda fut: decrease_counter())

    await wait_for_free() # wait until counter == 0
    switch_context()  # Log in to a different account

async def operation():
  # do stuff
  decrease_counter()
  sleep(60) # Long background operation
  await wait_for_context()  # Wait for context to come back and be 1.
  # continue

When there is only one chain of operations, this mechanism works well. Inner functions can always release the counter and take it back after the operation.
Unfortunately, when there are two operations running at the same time, it stops working:
async def operation():
  increase_counter()
  task1 = asyncio.create_task(sub_op())
  task1.add_done_callback(decrease)
  increase_counter()
  task2 = asyncio.create_task(sub_op())
  task2.add_done_callback(decrease)

  decrease_counter()
  await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
  await wait_for_context()

async def sub_op():
  decrease_counter()
  sleep(60)
  await wait_for_context()

The counter in that case is advanced as follows:
run_op (+1 = 1)
task1_creation (+1 = 2)
task2_creation (+1 = 3)
gather_release (-1 = 2)
task1_sleep (-1 = 1)
task2_sleep (-1 = 0)  # Context released
task1_resume (+1 = 1)
task2_resume (+1 = 2)
task1_done_callback (-1 = 1)
task2_done_callback (-1 = 0)  # Context needlessly released
gather_resume (+1 = 1)

Is it possible to prevent the needless release or is that just a fact of life when using such a mechanism? If so, is there any other mechanism that can solve the issue besides using a counter?

Thisi is a bit confusing and it is not quite a [mre]. You have a function run_operation that references a queue but there are no calls to this function (your second operation function is directly calling create_task instead)  It looks like in your first operation function your call to decrease_counter is to relinquish control of the shared resource and the subsequent call to wait_for_free is to regain access (does wait_for_free increase the counter before returning?).  Wouldn't a asyncio.Condition instance be applicable?

@Booboo I fear that a minimal reproducible example would not be minimal, so I preferred a pseudo-code. wait_for_context() will add a future back to the queue so it can be called again (implicitly increasing the counter before returning).
decrease_counter relinquishes control once the counter is 0, by triggering the future held by wait_for_free(). It does not increase the counter. I'm not sure how such aCondition would work. I believe it doesn't suffice as the context is released when the counter is 0, and for every sub-op there may be a count of 0 before returning from gather().

Update
According to the documentation for asyncio.Lock:

When more than one coroutine is blocked in acquire() waiting for the lock to be unlocked, only one coroutine eventually proceeds.
Acquiring a lock is fair: the coroutine that proceeds will be the first coroutine that started waiting on the lock.

I am working on the assumption that we do not have multiple threads working with contexts but that a task that has acquired its context might (because of a recursive call, for example) attempt to re-acquire the context. So we need to implement a recursive asyncio lock.
In class Context you can modify the __init__ method to do whatever initialization is required and modify acquire to add whatever code needs to be done to "activate" a context (such as update account information in a shared session instance).
import asyncio
import random
import time

class Context:
    """Context-specific information"""

    _lock = asyncio.Lock()

    def __init__(self):
        self._acquisition_count = 0
        ...  # Any other initializations

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.acquire()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_t, exc_v, exc_tb):
        self.release()

    async def acquire(self):
        assert self._acquisition_count >= 0

        if self._acquisition_count > 0:
            # Already acquiried
            self._acquisition_count += 1
            return

        await Context._lock.acquire()
        self._acquisition_count = 1
        print(f'Context {self} is acquired.')

    def release(self):
        assert self._acquisition_count >= 0

        if self._acquisition_count == 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Attempting to release unacquired Context')

        self._acquisition_count -= 1
        if self._acquisition_count == 0:
            Context._lock.release()
            print(f'Context {self} is released.')

async def sub_op(id, recursion_level, context=None):
    # Create and initialize your context
    if context is None:  # recursion_level is 0
        context = Context()
        print(f'sub_op({id}) context is {context}')

    # Acquire the context:
    async with context:
        print(f'sub_op({id}) working with context {context} recursion_level {recursion_level} at {time.time()}')

        # Do some work:
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

        if recursion_level < 2:
            await sub_op(id, recursion_level + 1, context)

    # Context has been released now if recursion_level == 0:

    if recursion_level == 0:
        # Do other stuff
        print(f'sub_op({id}) is doing other stuff without the context')
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

        print(f'sub_op({id})) finishing')

    # Re-acquire the context:
    async with context:
        print(f'sub_op({id}) working with context {context} recursion_level {recursion_level} again at {time.time()}')

        # Do some work:
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))


async def create_and_run_tasks():
    tasks = [
        sub_op(i, 0) for i in range(1, 4)
    ]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    print('All tasks completed.')

asyncio.run(create_and_run_tasks())

Prints:
sub_op(1) context is <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810>
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> is acquired.
sub_op(1) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> recursion_level 0 at 1727870349.2301354
sub_op(2) context is <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00>
sub_op(3) context is <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0>
sub_op(1) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> recursion_level 1 at 1727870351.2462912
sub_op(1) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> recursion_level 2 at 1727870353.2620366
sub_op(1) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> recursion_level 2 again at 1727870355.265821
sub_op(1) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> recursion_level 1 again at 1727870358.2801208
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> is released.
sub_op(1) is doing other stuff without the context
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> is acquired.
sub_op(2) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> recursion_level 0 at 1727870361.2902272
sub_op(2) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> recursion_level 1 at 1727870363.3041615
sub_op(1)) finishing
sub_op(2) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> recursion_level 2 at 1727870366.3329504
sub_op(2) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> recursion_level 2 again at 1727870368.3357255
sub_op(2) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> recursion_level 1 again at 1727870369.3473732
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> is released.
sub_op(2) is doing other stuff without the context
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> is acquired.
sub_op(3) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> recursion_level 0 at 1727870370.360742
sub_op(2)) finishing
sub_op(3) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> recursion_level 1 at 1727870373.3786244
sub_op(3) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> recursion_level 2 at 1727870376.3861718
sub_op(3) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> recursion_level 2 again at 1727870377.3960333
sub_op(3) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> recursion_level 1 again at 1727870380.398755
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> is released.
sub_op(3) is doing other stuff without the context
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> is acquired.
sub_op(1) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> recursion_level 0 again at 1727870382.4092572
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17ABE810> is released.
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> is acquired.
sub_op(2) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> recursion_level 0 again at 1727870383.4149687
sub_op(3)) finishing
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A90E00> is released.
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> is acquired.
sub_op(3) working with context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> recursion_level 0 again at 1727870385.415152
Context <__main__.Context object at 0x0000022A17A917C0> is released.
All tasks completed.


So that is the basic solution for a non-reentrant context. Per my example with operation() and sub_op(), the problem arises when it is reentrant with multiple sub operations running at the same time, some of them using the same context and releasing it for certain periods of time during long operations. At that point, gaps occur in the holding of the context which causes it to release and switch prematurely. I can perhaps create a better, runnable example, but it would be at least 5x longer - which is why I (maybe wrongly) chose to stick with pseudocode.

See updated answer and determine if this works with your usage of contexts. This is all I have left.
